# Including Typescript file from Svelte component w/ Rollup shows parsing error

Tags: typescript, svelte, vscode-extensions, rollupjs

### Brief Background

- I want to make a Visual Studio Code extension that has webviews
- I wanted to use Svelte/Typescript to make the webviews, Typescript to make the extension itself
- This has led me to an unusual project structure, where I use esbuild to build the extension, rollup to build the webviews, and use separate tsconfig.json for webviews compared to the extension

### What's Wrong?

I keep getting a parsing error when trying to do the webview rollup build:

```
src/webviews/pages/LogViewerPage.ts → out/compiled/LogViewerPage.js...
[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
src/core/LogData/LogData.ts (1:12)
1: import type { ILogData } from "./ILogData";
               ^
2: 
3: export class LogData implements ILogData {
Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
    at error (C:\...\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:198:30)
    at Module.error (C:\...\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:12560:16)
    at Module.tryParse (C:\...\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:12937:25)
    at Module.setSource (C:\...\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:12842:24)
    at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (C:\...\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:22291:20)
```

### Context?

**Example repo here: https://github.com/svew/svelte-typescript-headache/tree/master**

src/core/LogData/LogData.ts:

```
import type { ILogData } from "./ILogData";

export class LogData implements ILogData {

    private _name: string;
    
    constructor (name: string) {
        this._name = name;
    }
    get name(): string {
        return this._name;
    }
}
```

src/webviews/components/LogViewer.svelte:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { LogData } from "@core/LogData";

    let logData: LogData | undefined;

    onMount(() => {
        logData = new LogData("MyLogData");
    });
</script>

<body>
    {#if logData}
        <p>{logData.name}</p>
    {/if}
</body>
```

src/webviews/tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",
    "include": [
        "./**/*",
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules/*",
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "rootDir": "../",
        "baseUrl": "../",
        "paths": {
            "@core/*": [
                "./core/*",
            ],
            "@webviews/*": [
                "./webviews/*",
            ],
        },
        "types": [
            "node",
            "svelte",
        ],
    }
}
```

rollup.config.js:

```js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import nodeResolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only';
import sveltePreprocess from "svelte-preprocess";

const production = process.argv.includes("prod");

const plugins = [
    svelte({
        //include: 'src/webviews/**/*.svelte',
        compilerOptions: {
            // enable run-time checks when not in production
            dev: !production,
        },
        preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
    }),

    // we'll extract any component CSS out into
    // a separate file - better for performance
    css({ output: 'bundle.css' }),

    typescript({
        tsconfig: "src/webviews/tsconfig.json",
        sourceMap: !production,
        inlineSources: !production,
    }),

    // If you have external dependencies installed from
    // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
    // some cases you'll need additional configuration -
    // consult the documentation for details:
    // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs
    nodeResolve({
        browser: true,
        dedupe: ['svelte']
    }),
    commonjs(),

    // If we're building for production (npm run build
    // instead of npm run dev), minify
    production && terser()
];

const pageName = "LogViewerPage";
export default {
    //input: "src/extension.ts",
    input: "src/webviews/pages/" + pageName + ".ts",
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: "iife",
        name: "app",
        file: "out/compiled/" + pageName + ".js",
    },
    plugins: plugins,
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false,
    },
};
```

### What I Have Tried:

- Modifying tsoncifg rootDir/baseUrl
- Modifying rollup.config.js's sveltePreprocessor arguments, especially the typescript args
- Modifying rollup.config.js's typescript plugin's arguments
- Updating to latest packages

Very stumped how to fix this

Comment: Same scenario for me! Did you find a solution?